# CSS Problems on Chrome and Safari even with prefixes

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, vendor-prefix

I have this part of CSS and I have problems on Chrome and Safari even though the whole CSS file has been prefixed with Autoprefixer (and double checked with Pleeeease). Any clue why ? It's supposed to be 2 boxes having a flex behaviour on row (.deuxcases), and each box has a flex behavior on column (2 x .case), but on Chrome and Safari it's all making a long messy line, works fine only on Firefox. I use Chrome 50 and Safari 8.0.2. Thank you

```
.deuxcases {
margin-top: 70px;
max-height: 60vh;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
-webkit-box-direction:normal;
-webkit-flex-direction:row;
    -ms-flex-direction:row;
        flex-direction:row;
-webkit-flex-wrap:nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap:nowrap;
        flex-wrap:nowrap;
-webkit-box-pack:justify;
-webkit-justify-content:space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack:justify;
        justify-content:space-between;
}

.case {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient:vertical;
-webkit-box-direction:normal;
-webkit-flex-direction:column;
    -ms-flex-direction:column;
        flex-direction:column;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-webkit-justify-content:center;
    -ms-flex-pack:center;
        justify-content:center;
-webkit-flex-wrap:wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap:wrap;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
-webkit-box-flex:1;
-webkit-flex:1;
    -ms-flex:1;
        flex:1;
padding:auto;
margin:10%;
height: auto;
min-width: 25vw;
box-shadow: .5em .5em .5em .5em #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or similar with your code so we can play around with it

Comment: Sure, sorry : there you are http://codepen.io/jgrandsenne/pen/KzGmvo

Comment: Why has my question been set to -1, is there a problem with it ?

Comment: I'm not sure, probably because your explanation is very vague and hard to follow. That actually makes it difficult for the rest of us to help. Could you try and explain better what is the issue, exactly?

Comment: Ok. There is flexbox having the class .deuxcases. Inside this box, there is 2 elements, and they must appear in a row. And each of these 2 elements is itself a flexbox, with elements inside supposed to appear in a column. Which works fine on Firefox, but on Chrome on Safari, columns are not displayed in column : all the elements are in a mess and all on the same line. You can check this link codepen.io/jgrandsenne/pen/KzGmvo in Firefox, structurally it's what I want, and if you open the same link in Safari or Chrome you will actually see the problem. Is this clearer ?

Comment: Consider taking your codepen and additional details you've placed in the comments, and integrating them into your question. Here's some more guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask | http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always try setting `height` and `width` to explicit values and not to `auto`. The latter works inconsistently across browsers, and that's why you are struggling with this layout.

Just set the height on the `.case` class to `100%` instead of `auto`, and it'll work as expected.

Like this:

```
.case {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction:normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction:column;
        -ms-flex-direction:column;
            flex-direction:column;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -webkit-justify-content:center;
        -ms-flex-pack:center;
            justify-content:center;
    -webkit-flex-wrap:wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap:wrap;
            flex-wrap:wrap;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    -webkit-flex:1;
        -ms-flex:1;
            flex:1;
    padding:auto;
    margin:10%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 25vw;
    box-shadow: .5em .5em .5em .5em #aaa;
}
```

Comment: for images 100% height make them stretched, so faced similar troubles on safari, for safari I need to set image height to 100%, but on chrome it becomes stretched. Without this rule in chrome image is ok. Weird.... any ideas?